# reading file with ES6 promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

```
let arr = [];

function getData(fileName, type) {
    return fs.readFile(fileName,'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                arr.push(data[i]);
            }

            resolve();
        });
    });
}

getData('./file.txt', 'sample').then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

When I use above code and run it in command line using nodejs I get following error.

```
getData('./file.txt', 'sample').then((data) => {
                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Swap `return fs.readFile` with `return new Promise()`. You're returning `fs.readFile` which has no return value.

Comment: and you should use `reject` instead of `throw`

Comment: As already indicated by Marty you are returning the result of `fs.readFile()` which is not a Promise by definition as of the current version. You are probably confused based on the fact that inside a `then()` another Promise could be returned and would then be chained.

Answer (score 44):

You'll want to wrap the entire `fs.readFile` invocation inside a new `Promise`, and then reject or resolve the promise depending on the callback result:

```
function getData(fileName, type) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    fs.readFile(fileName, type, (err, data) => {
        err ? reject(err) : resolve(data);
    });
  });
}
```

[UPDATE] As of Node.js v10, you can optionally use the built-in Promise implementations of the `fs` module by using `fs.promises.<API>`. In the case of our `readFile` example, we would update our solution to use `fs.promises` like this:

```
function getData(fileName, type) {
  return fs.promises.readFile(fileName, {encoding: type});
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Nobody told about `util.promisify` so I'm going to post, however old the question is.
Why are you having this message?

```
getData('./file.txt', 'sample').then((data) => {
                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

`getData` is a wrapper for `fs.readFile` file here. `fs.readfile` is not a thenable (it does not implement a `then` function). It is built on the other pattern, the callback pattern. The most well-known thenable are Promises, and that's what you want to get from `readFile` I believe. A little reminder: [Mozilla - Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

So what you can do is either implement it yourself as did @hackerrdave or I would suggest using `promisify`: this function is a built-in function of Node.js which was implemented to transform the callback-based function into promised based. You will find it here: [Node.js Documentation for util.promisfy](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)

It basically does the same as @hackerrdave but it's more robust and built-in node util.

Here's how to use it:

```
const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');

const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile)
readFile("path/to/myfile").then(file => console.log(file))
```

Comment: I would enhance it with `const promisify = require('util').promisify;`, and then using directly `promisify(fs.readFile)("path/to/myfile").then( ... )`. Just remember the error argument of normal callback wont be present in `then` function, but in the `catch`

Comment: Indeed, I will add the catch statement, it will be clearer. And I ll edit as well the require statement, I did not think about that but no need to require the whole util.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a one-liner as of node 10.2.0:

`(async () => console.log(String(await require('fs').promises.readFile('./file.txt'))))();`

Yes, it is now out of the box.

Comment: Multiple lines would be better. This is hard to read and the V8 compiler will do optimisation for you.

Comment: `const readFilePromise = async file => await fs.promises.readFile( file );`

Answer (score 13):

As of Node 12+, you can use the [`fs.promises` API](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api).

See an example below:

```js
const { readFile } = require('fs').promises

readFile('./file.txt', { encoding: 'utf8' })
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

Using async/await

```js
const { readFile } = require('fs').promises

async function readFile(filePath) {
  try {
    const data = await readFile(filePath, { encoding: 'utf8' })
    console.log(data)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message)
  }
}

readFile('./file.txt')
```

Comment: This answer is valid as of [11+](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v11.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api), possible [10+](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api), verified in as early as 11.0 for the async/await portion though :) -- that is, earlier versions than quoted in this answer

Answer (score 10):

```
const getData = (fileName, type) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    fs.readFile(fileName, type, (err, data) => {
      //if has error reject, otherwise resolve
      return err ? reject(err) : resolve(data);
    })
  );

getData('./file.txt', 'utf8')
  .then(data => console.log('Data: ', data))
  .catch(error => console.log('Error: ', error));
```

Comment: It seems like the inner `return` may confuse the OP more?

Comment: I think you need to `return` the `new Promise` line, otherwise getData won't have a `then` defined on it.

Comment: @counterbeing The `return` is implicit for arrow functions without braces.

Answer (score 5):

**Update for current node** As of node 10.0.0 you can now use [`fs.promises`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readfile_path_options):

```
const fs = require('fs')

(async function(){
    var fileContents = await fs.promises.readFile(FILENAME)
    var data = JSON.parse(fileContents)
})()
```