# use command line tool of nodejs to take a word as a parameter, and then read the contents of 3 files parallelly

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
Make a JavaScript command line tool to take a word as a parameter, and then read the contents of 3 files parallelly and count the occurrence of the said word in each of the files. 
Display the count in each of the file once it’s done.
```

what is the way of doing it in javascript or nodejs

Comment: Breaking your question to smaller ones:  
1. How to read the first word from command line?  
2. How to determine the file names?  
3. How to execute in parallel a task for each item of an array?  
4. How to read a file? Are files huge? Is streaming and partial string handling required?  
5. How to count the occurences of a word in a string using regex or string functions?  
Do you know how to do some of the above?  
Do you want specific answers only for some of the above?

Comment: @DimitriosTsalkakis how to read the 3 files parallel using node.js

Answer (score 0):

The wizdom you seek is in [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

To read one file inside Promise.all(), you may use something like [fs.readfile()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41203409/reading-file-with-es6-promises/41203531) for an example)