# Not able to read JSON file after writing to the same JSON file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to write to a json file where I will re-read the file again after it has been written into. However, my `console.log(readJson());` is showing me `undefined` when I try to re-read the file. Could anyone advise what I should do?

**helper.js**

```
const fs = require('fs')
const util = require('util');
const path = require('path')
const json_file = path.resolve(__dirname, "../json/metrics.json")



function readJson(){
    fs.readFile(json_file,function(err,data){
        if(err){
            return console.error(err)
        }
        let iplist = data.toString()
        iplist = JSON.parse(iplist)
        let str = JSON.stringify(iplist)
        return str
    })
}

function writeJson(ipdetails){

    fs.readFile(json_file,function(err,data){
        if(err){
            return console.error(err)
        }
        let iplist = data.toString()
        iplist = JSON.parse(iplist)
        iplist.table.push(ipdetails.data)
        let str = JSON.stringify(iplist)
        fs.writeFile(json_file,str,function(err){
            if(err){
                console.error(err);
            }
            console.log('returning readJson() below')
            console.log(readJson());
        })
    })
}


module.exports = {
    writeJson,
    readJson
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The `return str` is inside of the `readFile` callback you should either use promises or `fs.readFileSync` like this:

```
function readJson() {
    let data = fs.readFileSync(json_file)
    let iplist = data.toString()
    iplist = JSON.parse(iplist)
    let str = JSON.stringify(iplist)
    return str
}
```

The async way is a little harder:

```
function readJson() {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        fs.readFile(json_file, type, (err, data) => {
          let iplist = data.toString()
          iplist = JSON.parse(iplist)
          let str = JSON.stringify(iplist)
          return err ? reject(err) : resolve(str);
        })
    );
}
```

You call the async verison like this:

```
readJson().then((result) => {
  console.log(result)
})
```

[async file example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41203409/reading-file-with-es6-promises/41203531)

[Here is some information on async functions](https://medium.com/@_bengarrison/javascript-es8-introducing-async-await-functions-7a471ec7de8a)

Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: Thank your for your response. However, I think there is an error in your answer. Is `fs.readFileSync(json_file)` not suppose to have a callback where I can access `data`?

Comment: I am trying to use the `async` way and I am getting `undefined` when I try to do `readJson().then((result) => {
  console.log(result)
})`

Comment: yes, it does. But the async way does not though. I am really trying to understand how to make it work using async/await

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195300/discussion-between-anbcodes-and-applepie).