# How to return data from two nested callback function in nodejs

Tags: node.js, fs, aws-sdk-js

I need to return the s3Url array. How to return s3Url array and suggest me is there any other best way to upload the data to s3 and return the s3Url

```
exports.s3Media = fileName => {
          let s3Url = [];
          (async () => {
            for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
              await fs.readFile(`${fileName[i]}`, (err, data) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                const params = {
                  Bucket: `research-1`,
                  Key: fileName[i],
                  Body: JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)
                };
                s3.upload(params, function(s3Err, data) {
                  if (s3Err) throw s3Err;
                  s3Url.push(data.location);
                });
              });
            }
            return s3Url;
          })();
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more things wrong with your code. You are not using Async/Await in the right way.

1. Take a look at Async/Await: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function
2. If you want to go with the Async/Await you have to promisify readFile(), have a look at this answer here: [reading file with ES6 promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41203409/reading-file-with-es6-promises/41203531)
3. Why are you using a self invoking fn inside the s3Media, maybe you can make the whole fn async (this will return a promise)
4. The return is not in the right position

Dig a little on your own and you will get there. I hope it helps.