# await statement does not "wait"

Tags: node.js, async-await, discord.js

So I've got a function which is :

```
module.exports.play = async (client, channel, players) => {
    players.push(client.guilds.cache.first().members.cache.array().filter(mem => mem.user.username === "user1").map(mem => mem.user)[0]);
    players.push(client.guilds.cache.first().members.cache.array().filter(mem => mem.user.username === "users2").map(mem => mem.user)[0]);

    try {
        await beginMessage(players, channel);

        let playersCards = await beginGame(client, players);
        console.log(playersCards);

        emitter.on("stop", async () => {
            await channel.delete();
            console.log("jeu fini");
        });
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
    }    
};
```

and the is that the value of my variable 'playersCards' is print before the value is returned by the async function "beginGame". Here's beginGame's function code :

```
async function beginGame(client, players) {
    let playersCards = [];

    fs.readFile("Utils/cartes.json", 'utf8', async (err, data) => {
        if(err) console.log(err);

        let cartes = JSON.parse(data);
        cartes = cartes.cartes;

        await asyncForEach(players, async player => {
            let playerCards = await distributeCards(player, cartes);
            playersCards.push(playerCards);
        });

        return playersCards;
    });
}
```

Where could the problem be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `beginGame` returns a `Promise` with no value because `fs.readFile` took a callback which is called else where, so there is nothing to wait for.

```
async function beginGame(client, players) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let playersCards = [];
        return fs.readFile('Utils/cartes.json', 'utf8', async (err, data) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);

            let cartes = JSON.parse(data);
            cartes = cartes.cartes;

            await asyncForEach(players, async player => {
                let playerCards = await distributeCards(player, cartes);
                playersCards.push(playerCards);
            });

            return resolve(playersCards);
        });
    });
}
```

this should work since the function is wrapped with promise and there is something to wait for.

Comment: `beginGame` is async, so its return value is converted to a promise by default.

Comment: Thank's it worked but as @VLAZ said the return value shoudl be converted to a promise, doesn't it ?

Comment: @andrc it *does*. I was correcting the first sentence of the answer, since it's misleading - an async function *always* returns a Promise. However, since you don't have a `return` anywhere *in the `beginGame` function*, it implicitly returns `undefined`, which is also turned into a Promise. So you never actually receive anything after the `await` because it resolves to `undefined`. For more information on `readFile` and promises [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41203409/reading-file-with-es6-promises). Seems there is a Node API that directly returns a Promise for it

Comment: @VLAZ you are correct it is returning a promise but with no value because fs.readFIle has a callback, i changed the answer.

Comment: @andrc can you accept the answer if it meet your requirement ?